# How to pass an IEnumerable <model> to a Modal view with MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, modal-dialog, partial-views

You want to open a modal that displays a list of products, for this you have the following button that opens the modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" id="pedirDesayuno" href="#myDesayunoPartial" class="btn btn-info">Desayunos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> </a>
```

in my main view you have the modal and the section where I refer my script

```
<!-- Modal PartialView -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myDesayunoPartial" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te">Espere Porfavor...</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/PartialViews/Modal.js"></script>
}
```

my script Modal.js:

```
$("#pedirDesayuno").click(function (eve) {

    $("modal-content").load("/Ordens/PedirDesayuno");
});
```

and my controller that opens the list:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PedirDesayuno()
{
   var listadesayuno = db.Productoes.Where(c => c.CategoriaProducto.v_Nombre == "DESAYUNO").ToList();
    return View(listadesayuno);
}
```

and my partialview PedirDesayuno.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<SistemaComandas.Models.Producto>


<h2>Agregar Producto</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Error</h3>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        <div class="form-horizontal">       
            <table class="table table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped table-hover">
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.v_Nombre)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio_Unitario)
                    </th>

                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.v_Nombre)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio_Unitario)
                        </td>

                        <td>                          
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>        
        </div>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that my modal window does not open the list of products and only comes to load a part as shown in the figure:

[image: Modal]

what am I doing wrong? How can I receive a list in a modal view? any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("modal-content")` returns `undefined` (it is not a valid selector). If you want the element with `class="modal-content"` then it would need to be

```
$(".modal-content").load("/Ordens/PedirDesayuno");
```

However, what I suspect your really want is

```
$(".modal-body").load("/Ordens/PedirDesayuno");
```

so that you do not remove the close button and title from the dialog.

In addition, your `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` are pointless since you do not have any form controls, and you need to remove the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags from the partial, including the scripts.